# select xls inserted data into Blob field in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

there is a Blob column in my table test.in Blob column an xlsx data has inserted in this column using java front end.

I want to view the data in the blob column(4 coloumns is available i excel sheet).

I have used utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(blob_field))

but its not help us to view the xls data.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view XLS data stored in BLOB's you can use SQLDeveloper. In the data grid of the table double click the field, click the pencil icon that appears. An 'Edit value' window pops up.
In the 'Saved data' tab choose 'External Editor' to open file with excel or choose 'Download'.

[image]

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the update!

can you please let us know any way to view this xls data in Blob field using sql command.?

Comment: The BLOB contains binary data, I do not understand how you can display the contents of a binary object using SQL in a meaningfull way. Only thing I can think of is to convert it to Base64 in a CLOB and display that.